# Question about the solution of the polynomial $(x−1)(x−2)⋯(x−n)−1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}\left [ x \right ]$ for all $n≥1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

The solution of the polynomial $(x−1)(x−2)⋯(x−n)−1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}\left [ x \right ]$  for all $n≥1$ is in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1691272/1012992).

I think it's no problem that do the same thing on $\mathbb{Q\left [ x \right ] }$ and $\mathbb{R\left [ x \right ]}$ and get the same result that  the polynomial $(x−1)(x−2)⋯(x−n)−1$ is irreducible.

But my question is  on $\mathbb{R\left [ x \right ]}$, the polynomial is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, let
$$f(x):=(x−1)(x−2)⋯(x−n)−1$$
Obviously,$f(1)=-1<0;\;f(n+1)=n!-1>0$, so there is a solution between $0$ and $(n+1)$ which means the polynomial is reducible. There's a contradiction, so which part is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: The irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are of degree $1$ or $2$. Once you have a real root $r$ there is a factor $x-r$. If there is a complex root $r$, then since the coefficients are real the complex conjugate $\overline{r}$ is also a root. Therefore, the polynomial is divisible by $x^2-(r+\overline{r})x+|r|^2$

Comment: For the irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ you can deduce it from that in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ using [Gauss' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)#The_lemma_over_the_integers)

Comment: @NDB Thank you! I completely understand now :)

Answer (score -1):

The logic doesn't generalize even to $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

> Then for the integers $1\leq k\leq n$, $h(k)=f(k)g(k)=-1$, so $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ must be one of the values $\pm 1$

What if $f(k) = \frac{1}{g(k)}$? This would be entirely permissible in $\mathbb{Q}$ since $k$ is rational and hence $g(k)$ is too, if $g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Of course, $1/n$ is a non-integer for integers $n$ (except $\pm 1$). Since $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \implies g(k) \in \mathbb{Z}$ (or more broadly, the evaluation of a polynomial over a ring, at an element in that ring, gives an element in that ring) this where they draw their conclusion in the linked post: it is clear the product must evaluate to $-1$, and the factors must be integers since they are polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ too.

Of course, then, this need not hold for polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Some playing around in WolframAlpha does suggest irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ regardless for $n \ge 2$, where nontrivial cases are concerned. My instinct is suggesting perhaps [the rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) may help in proving that irreducibility holds (i.e. prove that $n!-1$ is not a root for any $n$).

It does not hold over $\mathbb{R}[x]$, as you have seen.

Comment: See [Gauss' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)#The_lemma_over_the_integers)

Comment: I think your idea only holds over R[x], because in Gauss's lemma — A non-constant polynomial in Z[X] is irreducible in Z[X] if and only if it is both irreducible in Q[X] and primitive in Z[X]. So the polynomial is irreducible in Q[x] since it is irreducible in Z[x]

Comment: @Zhiwei: Your statement is not quite right; you need the polynomial to be non-constant *and primitive* (the gcd of the coefficients is $1$); but your polynomial is monic, and therefore it is necessarily primitive.